# Next.js errors with modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement server side rendering into my react application, that I have created earlier and now I'm using Next.js. I have tried to solve my problems through chatGPT but it doesn't helped me, I saw that many people have the same issue as I have, but other solutions are not helping me.

**My webpack version is 5.88.2**

Here is the code:

### next.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const BrowserifyZlib = require("browserify-zlib");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.resolve.alias["@components"] = path.join(
      __dirname,
      "src/components"
    );

    // Add fallback for core Node.js modules
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      fs: false,
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      zlib: BrowserifyZlib,
    };

    if (isServer) {
      // This is necessary for server-side rendering
      require("./scripts/generate-sitemap"); // Example: Generating a sitemap
    }

    return config;
  },
  env: {
    API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  },
  // Add your custom webpack plugins
  plugins: [],
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/(.*)",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "X-Frame-Options",
            value: "DENY",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  basePath: "/app",
};
```

### App.js:

```
import React from "react";

import { useState } from "react";

import MainScreen from "./MainScreen";
import AboutJinScreen from "./AboutJinScreen";
import UsefulScreen from "./UsefulScreen";
import ContactScreen2 from "./ContactScreen2";
import DisclaimerScreen from "./DisclaimerScreen";
import IndicationsScreen from "./IndicationsScreen";
import CompositionScreen from "./CompositionScreen";
import InstockScreen from "./InstockScreen";
import VideoScreen from "./VideoScreen";
import RealisationScreen from "./RealisationScreen";
import VerificationScreen from "./VerificationScreen";
import ContactScreen from "./ContactScreen";
import DocumentsScreen from "./DocumentsScreen";
import Footer_Com from "../components/Footer_Com";
import Link from "next/link"; // Import Next.js's Link component
import i18n from "../i18n";

const HomePage = () => {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(i18n.language);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <MainScreen />
      <AboutJinScreen />
      <UsefulScreen />
      <ContactScreen2 />
      <DisclaimerScreen />
      <IndicationsScreen />
      <CompositionScreen />
      <InstockScreen />
      <VideoScreen />
      <RealisationScreen />
      <VerificationScreen />
      <ContactScreen />
      <DocumentsScreen />
      <Footer_Com />

      {/* Use Next.js's Link component for navigation */}
      <Link href="/about">Go to About</Link>
      <Link href="/useful">Go to Useful</Link>
      <Link href="/contact">Go to Contact</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

### Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Router } from "next/router"; // Import Next.js's Router
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
import HomePage from "./pages/App";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom";


const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      {/* Use Next.js's Router for client-side navigation */}
      <Router>
        <HomePage />
      </Router>
    </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```